# Cannot use import outside of a module

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules

I'm currently rewriting my discord bot from JavaScript to TypeScript. While doing so I encountered a SyntaxError:`Cannot use import statement outside a module`. From other questions it seemed that adding `"type" : "module",` in `package.json` should fix it. However this results in another TypeError:`Unknown file extension ".ts"`.

What is proper way of fixing this so I can use import statements in `index.ts` and other files?

index.ts:

```
import {Client, Intents} from "discord.js";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();
const token = process.env.TOKEN;

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.login(token);
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "wdr",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A discord bot",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "type" : "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "wdr",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@discordjs/rest": "^0.1.0-canary.0",
    "discord-api-types": "^0.24.0",
    "discord.js": "^13.3.1",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["ESNext"],
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "strict": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": [
    "index.ts",
    "commands/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: I think you compile options is the issue. Its saying module: commonjs.

Comment: share your ts config

Comment: @Tiko The tsconfig.json is there.

Comment: isn't it better to just `include` the whole `*.ts` directly?

Comment: Just fixed that. Error still continues however.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems you're just running `node .` or smth like that, to run your ts code. The problem is, node is going to run js files, and that's why ts is not recognized.

So to solve this issue, you can install `ts-node` , and add a run command in `package.json`

`npm i ts-node -D`

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "ts-node index.ts"
}
```

`npm run start`